# Does CommunityBuilding.SE want to participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion

The year is drawing to a close and Stack Exchange is planning another [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) (Winter 2013's link). We, as a community, get to decide if we'd like to participate in this event.

This event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

We have until December 1 to decide. If we do not make a decision by then, we are opt'd **IN** by default.

Does Moderators.SE want to gather hats this winter?

Answer (score 16):

Don't be a hater... be a hatter!  Bring on the Hats!!!